# react: preventing form submission not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, form-submit, dom-events

I have written some code which is mentioned below in the snippet. It posts `form` data to the server in order to download a `CSV` file. Chrome is working as expected. However, in Firefox, the page always reloads when calling the `downloadCSV` function.

The following `a` element is contained in one of my components. Clicking it, triggers the `downloadCSV` function.

```
<a ref='downloadAnchor' onClick={this.downloadCsv.bind(this)}>
    <i className='fa fa-download' />
    Download as CSV
</a>
```

and the function

```
function downloadCsv() {
    const query = {
        name: 'someName',
        age: 'someAge',
        bla: 'blabla',
        someOtherField: 'bla'
    };

    const form = document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('action', 'some_url');
    form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });

    // _ is lodash
    _.forEach(query, (v, k) => {
        const input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        input.setAttribute('name', k);
        input.setAttribute('value', v);

        form.appendChild(input);
    });

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(form);
}
```

Comment: Could you include your code where you call `downloadCsv`?

Comment: Try adding target="_blank"

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, but it might be worth trying preventing the default behavior of the anchor tag click as well. `function downloadCsv(event) { event.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: Looks like a [x y problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) to me. Here's what you're doing in your function : creating hidden forms, setting their values, submitting the form to launch a POST HTTP request and then deleting the form. Can't you post your data any other way? For instance, why can't you send a POST ajax request and handle the response?

Comment: @UllasHunka, Tholle: the combination of your suggestions work, but I kinda don't like the new tab opening and closing really quicky. Could this be improved?

Comment: @GuillaumeGeorges because the CSV download is initiated in the server and not in the client. The client just sends the `POST` data

Comment: @XeniaSis Just `event.preventDefault();` by itself didn't work?

Comment: @Tholle, no I also needed `form.setAttribute('target', '_blank');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FIrefox doesn't preventing dispatched submit event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49587933/firefox-doesnt-preventing-dispatched-submit-event)

Comment: How is this a possible duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a combination of @UllasHunka and @Tholle 's comments. The working code looks like the following:

```
function downloadCsv(event) {
    // ----->
    event.preventDefault();

    const query = {
        name: 'someName',
        age: 'someAge',
        bla: 'blabla',
        someOtherField: 'bla'
    };

    const form = document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('action', 'some_url');
    form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
    // ----->
    form.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

    form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });

    // remove limit to get all logs
    query.limit = 0;

     _.forEach(query, (v, k) => {
         const input = document.createElement('input');
         input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
         input.setAttribute('name', k);
         input.setAttribute('value', v);

         form.appendChild(input);
    });

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(form);
}
```